# Java won't stop looping my if statements

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This may be an obvious answer but it is due tomorrow and I am completely stumped. Everything is working fine except for the if statements at the end. It seems the continueGame loop is looping the if statement infinitely. If anyone can help me with this problem, please.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class HighLOw {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String input = null;
        int number = 0;
        int tries = 0;
        boolean highorlow = false;
        boolean continueGame = false;
        boolean validInput = false;
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = (random.nextInt(101));

        System.out.println("Welcome to the High/Low game.");
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 100.");
        System.out.println(
                "In order to print a random number, type your number in the console and press enter.");
        System.out.println("Keep going until you get the right number.");
        System.out.println("Have fun.");
        System.out.println(randomNumber);

        while (continueGame == false) { 

            while (validInput == false) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // BufferedReader variable where the user will input their answer

                    input = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    number = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    validInput = true;

                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { 
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a number.");
                    validInput = false;
                }

                if (number < 0 || number > 100) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Error, you must enter a number that is between 0 and 100");
                    validInput = false;
                }
            }

            if (number < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println(
                        number + " is too low. Please try a higher number");
                tries++;
                highorlow = false;
            } else if (number > randomNumber) {
                System.out.println(
                        number + " is too high. Please try a lower number");
                tries++;
                highorlow = false;
            } else if (number == randomNumber) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Congratulations, you guessed the right number. Now go outside.");
                tries++;
                System.out.println("It took you " + tries + (" tries."));
                System.out.println("Game Ended");
                continueGame = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few hints: When you enter a valid number for the first time, `validInput` will become `true`. Then, the code proceeds to compare `number` to `randomNumber` and then jumps up again to the start of the `continueGame` loop. What is the value of `validInput` now, and what effect will this have on the `validInput` loop? Will `number` ever get a new value?

Also you don't need to do `while (validInput == false)`..  Just `while (!validInput)` is equivalent..

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It's working 100% now. That was quite a noob mistake but I just started using java.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `if/else` statements are evaluated from top to bottom. Once a matching `if` is found its body is executed and it exits.

Keeping this in mind, that means a given evaluation of an `if/else` structure has only one `case` where the body will get executed.

Look at your `if` clauses and think about them like a number line(Or better yet draw a number line with some examples of what `number` and `randomNumber` could be) and see if the answer jumps out at you.